# Namenode Startup issue

Tags: hadoop

Not able to start NameNode after installation. 
Getting the below error 
​
!NameNode Start
stderr: /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-1775.txt
​
​File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call

```
raise Fail(err_msg)
```

resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ;  /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode'' returned 1. starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-thdppca0.out
​Namenode log file:
​ulimit -a for user hdfs core file size (blocks, -c) unlimited data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited scheduling priority (-e) 0 file size (blocks, -f) unlimited pending signals (-i) 128331 max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64 max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited open files (-n) 128000 pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8 POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200 real-time priority (-r) 0 stack size (kbytes, -s) 10240 cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited max user processes (-u) 65536 virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited file locks (-x) unlimited

---

### ​​Ip :inet addr:10.47.84.5

Need help to resolve this issue. Let me know if you more details needs to be shared.Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you formatted the namenode post installation?

Comment: I was installing through ambari..i didnt format name node manually. But I got the error in the Ambari installation last step,I was able to complete the installation with that.

Comment: Is your namenode is in safemode? Or it is not starting at all?

Comment: Do you see any error messages in /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-1775.txt ? If yes, please post the error message. I am afraid your installation hasn't finished properly.

Comment: @Karthi Run this command `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode` manually from the namenode host and post the error.

Comment: @ Rahul below is the Name node log info: @franklinsijo i tried that too it was not working.
In the log i got the msg like
WARN namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:loadFromDisk(690)) - Encountered exception loading fsimage java.io.FileNotFoundException: /trvapps/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION (Permission denied) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) at   
..........
ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1712)) - Failed to start namenode
...........................
should i change the permission?
chown -R hdfs:hdfs /trvapps/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION

Comment: Is `/trvapps/` the custom directory provided by you during Installation?

Comment: I am not sure,I dont remember i gave this path...will it work if I change the owner?

Comment: Need more information, Who owns `/trvapps`?

Comment: its a mount point owned by root.

Comment: @frank 
I found the same dir and files created in two places.
/var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current and also under
/trvapps/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current 
All have root:root as their owner
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     201 Feb 13 10:12 VERSION

Comment: Let the `/trvapps` be owned by root, change the ownership of `/trvapps/hadoop` recursively to `hdfs`. From the previous error, It looks like `/trvapps/hadoop` is being used for HDFS and not `/var/hadoop`.

Comment: yes I have changed that and i got the same error for other path changed that too and i got the same error again for /vmcore/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current changed that also after that name node is up. But apptimelines server not up got some error I am working on that. will post the details below.

Comment: this is the error :RemoteException": {
    "exception": "SafeModeException", 
    "javaClassName": "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException", 
    "message": "Cannot set permission for /ats/done. Name node is in safe mode.\nThe reported blocks 0 needs additional 535 blocks to reach the threshold 1.0000 of total blocks 534.\nThe number of live datanodes 0 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached."
  }
i turned off safemode manually.

Comment: Rectified all problem and cluster is up and running thank you guys.